# How to generate request format for WCF web service method for Mac and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am not able to generate request format for WCF web service method for iOS and Mac project bot.  which accepts an object as a parameter. Used service url is “ https:// “ for security concern. I am using “WSDL2Objc Parser” and “Sudz-c” both to generate proxy files but its not working properly ( like : it generate some syntax error while creating files) . web service is implemented in .Net language.

At Server side  (.Net) we are using wsHttpBinding to be able to use SOAP 1.2 but we can't generate the client proxies - which is dead easy on the Windows box but not so easy on a Mac or iOS.